# What can affect a server's ssh console respond time?

Tags: ssh, ping, network-speed

I have two servers.

The ping respond time of them are both about 210 ms.

But the ssh respond time is quite different. One is fast(~200ms) while another is quite slow(~1s).
CPU and memory of these two servers are different. But CPU usage are both 0% when I'm testing.

What can be the root cause of this huge difference of ssh respond time?

Comment: Define better what you see as response time. Is it during login, or after having logged in and typing in the shell?

Comment: It's the response of my typing in the shell. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's a chance that it's routing. It's called asynchronous routing if a network takes very different paths in and out of their network. Since you have logins at both ends run traceroute (use mtr) to check any obvious differences. Paste them here if you need a hand interpreting them.

I didn't ask if you are just referring to response times at login and not during use. Disable reverse lookups at login with 'UseDNS no' in sshd_config for general use and testing.

--EDIT--

When you start your SSH client use `ssh -c blowfish user@host`. This should speed up the slower connection using faster encryption.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The tracert for both hosts are similar in regards of hops and the delay.
Setting "UseDNS no" seems having some help.